# EF Core - How to create inherited entity types that contain foreign key columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using the table per hierarchy approach for achieving inheritance in entity types. I have 3 classes defined:

**Room** - Base class

**SubMapRoom** - Inherits from Room

**OverviewRoom** - Inherits from Room

In the DB, I just have 1 table called Room that has both the SubMapRoom and OverviewRoom columns in it. It also contains the Discriminator column for specifying which type it is.

First, I attempted to move all of the SubMapRoom columns in the Room class into the SubMapRoom class. 1 of the columns contains a foreign key to a different table called Status. After doing this, I tried specifying the foreign key relationship for the SubMapRoom entity type in OnModelCreating(). However, I get a compile error when I try to do this. In the EF Core OnModelCreating() method, I have this code (marked the line that contains the error below):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SubMapRoom>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(d => d.UnassignedDoctorStatus)
        .WithMany(p => p.Room) **ERROR HAPPENS HERE**
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.UnassignedDoctorStatusId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Room_UnassignedStatusID");
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Room>()
    .HasDiscriminator<int>("RoomType")
    .HasValue<SubMapRoom>(1)
    .HasValue<OverviewRoom>(2);
```

I get this error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

I know that I can solve this by changing the other class (Status) to use the inherited type instead of the base type for the navigation property, but that seems like the wrong way to go. I feel like I am missing something here. What would be the correct way to define a foreign key relationship in an inherited entity type?

[EDIT]
Here are the classes for the 4 models I have referenced here:

```
public abstract class Room
{
    public Room()
    {
        InverseLinkedRoom = new HashSet<Room>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SubMapId { get; set; }
    public string MapLabel { get; set; }
    public string RoomLabel { get; set; }
    public int LeftCoordinate { get; set; }
    public int TopCoordinate { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int? LinkedRoomId { get; set; }
    public int RoomType { get; set; }

    public Room LinkedRoom { get; set; }
    public SubMap SubMap { get; set; }
    public PatientQueue PatientQueue { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Room> InverseLinkedRoom { get; set; }
}

public class SubMapRoom : Room
{
    public int? UnassignedDoctorStatusId { get; set; }

    public Status UnassignedDoctorStatus { get; set; }
}

// Note: Have not yet attempted to move base class members in here
public class OverviewRoom : Room
{
}

public partial class Status
{
    public Status()
    {
        Room = new HashSet<Room>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EnumId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool IsFastBlink { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Room> Room { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to add your model listings for all 4 models here

Comment: I have added the 4 model classes at the end.

Comment: Ok, so your problem, really, is that you're trying to define the relationship two-way from within a sub entity. I would try this, instead:

`modelBuilder.Entity<SubMapRoom>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(d => d.UnassignedDoctorStatus)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.UnassignedDoctorStatusId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Room_UnassignedStatusID");
});`

`modelBuilder.Entity<Status>(e => { e.HasMany(i => i.Room); });`

Comment: Tried that and got this error: ReferenceNavigationBuilder<SubMapRoom, Status>' does not contain a definition for 'HasForeignKey' and no extension method 'HasForeignKey' accepting a first argument of type 'ReferenceNavigationBuilder<SubMapRoom, Status>' could be found

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone. I reviewed my DB schema and decided to make some changes that make this problem go away. It actually turns out that my new schema is easier to use in the code than I originally thought. In fact, it's a lot easier. I think I was trying to overengineer this. So sometimes, the solution is to review your schema and figure out if it even makes sense in the first place. Basically, what I did was move the inherited classes to a separate table with a separate ID. Because, at the end of the day, they are logically separate types of entities and only related in terms of the data. In the code, they serve much different purposes even though they share some of the same columns.

At the end of it all, the only disadvantage of this approach is that I am violating DRY on another table (there are 5 repeated columns in it). Otherwise, a lot of other operations are easier to code than before. I am willing to live with that instead of dealing with all of this for now. Later, I can try to use Table Per Hierarchy if I am having to add tons of new columns to both tables.